# WPToolkitTestFx: Getting unhandled exception when assertfailed

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8

I am using WPToolkitTestFx Unit test framework for the Windows Phone 8 application. I am getting below error when I am executing `Assert.Fail()` or `Assert.IsFalse(true)`.

> A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Phone.DLL

Any solution to the above error.

Here the source code

```
    [TestMethod]
    [Asynchronous]
    [Description("Test2: Sample asynchronous test")]
    public void Test2()
    {
        // this test executes asynchronously
        Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
        {
            // ... and then fails

            Assert.IsFalse(true);

            EnqueueTestComplete();
        });
    }
```

Thanks,
Ragu

Comment: Hmm that's the whole point - your assertion failed ... which throws an exception. What would you have it do?

Comment: It should add in the result as failed and should continue other tests, but it crashes the entire application.

Answer (score 0):

I can see something similar when following the sample code from http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/20/windows-phone-toolkit-overview.aspx.

It is normal for the exception to occur, and see:

`A first chance exception of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.AssertFailedException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTesting.Phone.DLL`

Also if the debugger is attached to your device/emulator, the debugger will break so you can find out where the test failure was.

```
    private void Application_UnhandledException(object sender, ApplicationUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        if (Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // An unhandled exception has occurred; break into the debugger
            Debugger.Break(); // <- !!! application will stop in debugger here !!!
        }
    }
```

However if you continue the project (press F5), or are not running under the debugger, you will see that the application continues to run and doesn't get exited.

That allows you to see your test results.

Answer (score -1):

Question, is it a normal part of your test to fail the assertion? if so, you need to instruct the framework to expect such exception to happen

```
[TestMethod, Asynchronous]
[Description("Test2: Sample asynchronous test")]
[ExpectedException(typeof(AssertFailedException))]
public void Test2()
{
    // this test executes asynchronously
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        // ... and then fails

        Assert.IsFalse(true);

        //TestComplete();
    });
}
```

Also I notice that you are marking the method as Asynchronous, but you are not using the asynchronous invocation methods of `EnqueueDelay(TimeSpan), EnqueueCallback(), EnqueueTestComplete()` are the ones that make the method function asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry I am using EnqueueTestComplete(), I edited my post. I added ExpectedException, but still crashing the application.

Comment: This is a bad idea - the test is failing and the `AssertFailedException` is the way that the framework reports this.